# How to rename files on MacOS Big Sur 11.4 using Python 3.9.5, not batch or sequential, using a list/CSV file(s)?

Tags: python, macos

I have found many questions that have helped me get to where I am at now, but am stuck moving forward.

End goal: I have ~1500 audio files with meaningless names (each 9 characters long and a mix of numbers and letters; i.e. 4a96det8g).  I have a table with the meaningless name in one column and a useful name in a second column (for example: Getting There).  I want to rename all files to the useful name that coincides with the meaningless names, and then keep whatever extension is on each file (there is a mix of .m4a and .mp4).

Where I am at in Python:
I have split the table in 2 different CSV files, and loaded them into IDLE as lists: ID_List (meaningless names) and Names_List (useful list). I have not sort the lists in Python, so each index is applicable to the same index in the other list.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
for i in ID_List:
    for file in os.listdir("/Volumes/2TB Portabl/Audios copy 2"):
        if(file.startswith(ID_List[i])):
            oldtext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
            os.rename(file, Names_List[i] + oldtext)
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#30>", line 3, in <module>
    if(file.startswith(ID_List[i])):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

So somewhere I am needing to force the return from ID_List to be a string??? Or maybe there is an easier way to do this all together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate through the values in the list, not the index. That's why `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` occurs. Try to iterate by the index.

```
for i in range(len(ID_List)):
    for file in os.listdir("/Volumes/2TB Portabl/Audios copy 2"):
        if(file.startswith(ID_List[i])):
            oldtext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
            os.rename(file, Names_List[i] + oldtext)
```

Comment: Well, there is no error now, but now it does not seem that anything happens...

Comment: In that case, the values in the ID_List doesn't match with the filenames. Can you share some examples of the values in ID_List and some filenames?

Comment: You're right. ID_List does not contain file extensions; but I thought using startswith would accommodate for that...Should I try a splitext[0] somewhere in there instead? Or I think I can figure out a new CSV file that includes extensions...I'll try that first.

Comment: OK, I created a new CSV file and sorted to make sure my lists would match up.  The code you provided worked!  I got four files renamed and then it threw a file not found error, but I verified the original file is in fact present...so not sure what happened there...
I am going to add in an error handler to skip files if "not found" and see how many more will work.

Comment: Couldn't get the error handling to work out.  There ended up being 143 files in total that were "not found" but actually did exist.  Maybe there is a sorting requirement that did not work out for me.  But nevertheless, thanks for the help, manually renaming 143 files is a lot quicker than manually renaming 1500!